# How to migrate c# application to Web Control to use in SharePoint application

Tags: user-controls, rich-text, ajax-control-tookit

I have created C# application which use Microsoft.SharePoint Namespace.
That Application let the user to select the wiki page and available anchors inside that wiki page.
Now I migrated that C# Application to SharePoint Web Part.

My Problem is "I want to appear that application in new window(or popup window) when user click on the specific Icon or Link from rich Text Editor of wiki edit page."
My questions are

1. Should I use Ajax or J query or Java Script? IF I should use how can I change c# code into those scripts?

2.How can I add New Icon(With Link to my application) or New Link into SharePoint Rich Text Editor?

(I'm Using MOSS 2007)

With Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to develop the following:

- A web part which generate html with

  - A div which contains ajax to get the list of wiki pages, and when a page is selected ajax to get the anchors on that page
  - jQueryUI to hide/show that div as a dialog
  - Icon/link to activate jQueryUI
- A web service to respond to the above ajax calls
- A page layout to allow you to add the web part next to Content